# IIFE is not a function when used as a module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got this module,

```
// data.js
(async data => {
    const r = require('rethinkdb');

    const [err, conn] = await r.connect();
    console.log(conn, err);

    const pluck =   async (selectors, table) => await r.table(table).pluck(selectors).run(conn);
    const without = async (selectors, table) => await r.table(table).without(selectors).run(conn);
    const filter =  async (selectors, table) => await r.table(table).filter(selectors).run(conn);
    const get =     async (id, table) =>        await r.table(table).get(id).run(conn);
    const insert =  async (doc, table) =>       await r.table(table).insert(doc).run(conn);
    const update =  async (id, doc, table) =>   await r.table(table).get(id).insert(doc).run(conn);
    const remove =  async (id, doc, table) =>   await r.table(table).get(id).delete(doc).run(conn);
    const sample =  async (num, table) =>       await r.table(table).sample(num).run(conn);

    data.exports = {
        pluck,
        without,
        filter,
        get,
        insert,
        update,
        remove,
        sample,
    };
})(module).catch(console.log); // Line 26
```

Whenever I run this, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at __dirname (D:\Dropbox\Development\nodejs\statoshiluck.io\lib\data.js:26:1)
    at <anonymous>
```

I simply cannot figure out what to do, I've googled and googled, stackoverflowed and stackoverflowed. Please send help!

Comment: just the code looks strange which i think can be better structured. Need to know what you try to achieve

Comment: @FanCheung Could probably be, but as of right now, I'm just trying to make it work. Whenever I run it in my node script, I'm getting the above error.

Comment: What is module? I think you should be adding a parameter to data (call it m) which is is the pointer to module being passed in via the call to your iife. Then you should check if m is already created and if not then init it and set exports.

Comment: A part of nodejs

Comment: Similar to this pattern: http://jsbin.com/giciniz/edit?js

Comment: `console.log.bind(console)` might help.

Comment: Aside from the error you're getting, what are you expecting this to actually do?

Comment: @iOnline247 Same error.

Comment: @robertklep Just trying to export the actions listed in the export = {...}

Comment: @Mobilpadde exports can't be asynchronous, though.

Comment: @robertklep Oh, that's good to know, thanks!